# Is there a way to pass parameters when creating a Enyo app class?

Tags: enyo

I was going to try in pass in parameters when I create my Enyo app class in the index.html file. I have the following to test it

```
new MyApps.MainApp("test").renderInto(document.body);
```

and in the js file

```
create: function(in)
{
    Alert(in);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're really, really close.  If you want to set some variables on your app's kind then you need to pass the parameters as you would to any other kind.  Try:

```
 new MyApps.MainApp({test: true}).renderInto(document.body);
```

Then, you should be able to access the value of test as:  this.test

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I could not get iot to work, I have  new MyApps.MainApp( {atest: true} ).renderInto(document.body); and  if (this.atest)
  alert("worcked");
  else
  alert("did not worcked"); any idears?????

Comment: Sorry, never saw this response.  Did you ensure you called this.inherited(arguments) -before- you you checked `this.atest`?  It works:  http://jsfiddle.net/RoySutton/20ga6k0u/

Answer (score 0):

```
new MyApps.MainApp({test: true}).renderInto(document.body);
```

...

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "MyApps.MainApp",
    kind: enyo.VFlexBox,
    components: [],
    create: function(inArgs) {
        var args = inArgs;
        if (args.test) {
            this.log("SUCCESS");
        }

        this.inherited(arguments);
    }
});
```

Something like that.